# is there a way to send thorough email a component with external stylesheet styles?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, email, react-redux

I have a react app, and i want to send through email a component,
i extract the html of the component with this   `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.elementRef).innerHTML`. 
the inline styles are being sended, but the ones that came from a classname not.

Comment: All of your styles must be inline, you cannot send through an external CSS file with an email.

Comment: @APAD1 is there a way/method to get all the styles inline?

Comment: I know you can get all computed styles with https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle. But it may not be supported on every browser